# regex pick full word only

Tags: java, regex

I need to pick only a full word using regex,I don't want to pick a word if its contained in another word, but I do want to pick if it starts/ends with special characters like _test, test.,test/,test.

Example:I dont want to pick if a word is contained in other word like"context" if I am looking for "text". But want it if I am looking for full-text, /text,text.,text_test, text,text's.

EDIT: Since we cant identify the plural forms, I am deleting that part.

Comment: It's not possible to write a regular expression that knows what the plural of a word is without access to a word list. Do you have a word list available?

Comment: @mark i don't have a list of such words available

Comment: Then what you are asking is not possible.  There is no regex that will match any valid English word.

Comment: @sharma: By the way `test's` isn't the plural of `test` - the plural form is `tests` (without an apostrophe).

Comment: @mjg124 okay, I expected that but definitely thought we can search if the word is prefixed/suffixed by special characters we can find them.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I know, but still wanted to match it,it comes under the category followed by special characters.

Comment: So you are just looking for any group of letters which has non-letter characters either side of it?  It might be worth clarifying your question then.

Comment: @mjg12- I am looking to count the occurrences of the word in the line/text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will benefit a lot from completing a tutorial such as this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx
And Expresso is an excellent free tool for debugging and testing regular expressions.

Second, your expression should probably be something like:

\b([^A-Za-z]*|A-Za-z*[^A-Za-z]+)(text)([^A-Za-z]*|[^A-Za-z]+A-Za-z*)\b

\b word boundaries

([^A-Za-z]*|A-Za-z*[^A-Za-z]+) means "non alpha characters OR alpha characters followed by at least one non-alpha character"

"text" will be matched by subgroup 2.

Again, go through the tutorial above, it's short and you probably could have figured out how to create this expression in the time it's taken to get an answer here.

Comment: I realize now you're asking for something a little but more sophisticated because of the "full-text" case- so you might try removing the word boundaries (the \b on either side). For plurals, you could replace "text" with (text|texts)

Comment: [^w]* works for non-alphanumeric characters, except for text_ and _text , it does not seem to work for that case

Comment: Ah, you are correct, \w considers _ to be a word character. I edited my answer- the new expression should be complete.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a word contained in the variable `word` I suggest you use

```
"\\b\\Q" + word + "\\E\\b"
```

Here's a breakdown:

- `\b`: A word boundary
- `\Q`: Nothing, but quotes all characters until \E
- `\E`: Nothing, but ends quoting started by \Q

Something like this may do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\Q" + word + "\\E\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("word like \"context\" while looking for \"text\".");
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```